# No Ethernet Connectivity

Tags: networking, system-installation

### TL;DR:

My network (Ethernet) doesn't work until I (manually) run `sudo dhclient`,
but I need to do it every time I boot. 
How do I get it to stick on reboot?

### History:

I've booted up an Arch ISO.  I have a desktop with wired Ethernet, solid lights.  `ip link` gives us `[eno1]` and is `BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP`.

I've followed [Arch Linux - connect: Network is unreachable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80493/arch-linux-connect-network-is-unreachable#) to set up a netctl ethernet-dhcp profile for eno1 and enable it.

Does this config/profile look ok?  Despite enabling/starting it fails on reboot...

```
Description='A basic dhcp ethernet connection'
Interface=eno1
Connection=ethernet
IP=dhcp
#DHCPClient=dhcpcd
#DHCPReleaseOnStop=no
## for DHCPv6
#IP6=dhcp
#DHCP6Client=dhclient
## for IPv6 autoconfiguration
#IP6=stateless
```

If I `ping` any IP, (including 8.8.8.8 and 192.168.1.1), I get "Network is unreachable", and if I try google.co.uk, I get "temporary failure in name resolution".

`ifconfig` yields:

```
eno1: flags:4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>
inet: fe00::c42b:cd14:3908:6ea8
ether: 74:d4:35:1c:f0:3e
```

`sudo dhclient` results in the internet coming up, but on reboot, this is lost.

```
sudo netctl status mynet-eno1-dhcp
● netctl@mynet\x2deno1\x2ddhcp.service - A basic dhcp ethernet connection
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/netctl@mynet\x2deno1\x2ddhcp.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-05-06 22:11:28 BST; 19min ago
     Docs: man:netctl.profile(5)
  Process: 492 ExecStart=/usr/lib/netctl/network start mynet-eno1-dhcp (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 492 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 06 22:10:58 msc001 dhcpcd[537]: DUID 00:01:00:01:22:80:f1:8f:74:d4:35:1c:f0:3e
May 06 22:10:58 msc001 dhcpcd[537]: eno1: IAID 35:1c:f0:3e
May 06 22:10:58 msc001 dhcpcd[537]: eno1: soliciting a DHCP lease
May 06 22:11:28 msc001 network[492]: timed out
May 06 22:11:28 msc001 dhcpcd[537]: timed out
May 06 22:11:28 msc001 dhcpcd[537]: dhcpcd exited
May 06 22:11:28 msc001 network[492]: DHCP IPv4 lease attempt failed on interface 'eno1'
May 06 22:11:28 msc001 network[492]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'mynet-eno1-dhcp'
May 06 22:11:28 msc001 systemd[1]: netctl@mynet\x2deno1\x2ddhcp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 06 22:11:28 msc001 systemd[1]: netctl@mynet\x2deno1\x2ddhcp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

As neither dhcpcd, dhclient work completely, I'll be looking at Network Manager later, will report back.

How do I get it to stick on reboot?

Comment: have you tried dhclient? what does ifconfig say?

Comment: @vfbsilva dhclient works for that session, but on reboot it's lost it's connection again, any ideas?

Comment: I've added extra info and also added my netctl profile to see if there is a problem there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages indicate your netctl profile is using `dhcpcd` as the DHCP client, rather than `dhclient`.

Since it looks like `dhclient` works but `dhcpcd` doesn't, [you might try changing the default DHCP client to `dhclient`.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/netctl#Set_default_DHCP_client)

Either create `/etc/netctl/hooks/dhcp` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
DHCPClient='dhclient'
```

Or create `/etc/netctl/interfaces/eno1` with the following contents:

```
DHCPClient='dhclient'
```

In both cases, mark the file as executable (`chmod a+x <filename>`).

Comment: That's great, thanks.  sudo dhclient works whilst installing from the ISO, the above is perfect once rebooted.